# JENKINS .HPI dependencies issue

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am creating the .hpi jenkins plugin. 
The issue i am having is with the external jars, it is not getting picked up by my java code that is running. 
I am using maven so they are in the .hpi package inside the

web-inf/lib in the .hpi package

I have a menifest.mf file inside /META-INF directory in the .hpi pcakage

with the following

Class-Path: ./lib/car.jar ./lib/plane.jar 
PluginFirstClassLoader: true

this is what i have in the pom.xml file

'''
'''`<manifestFile>src/main/resources/custom/MANIFEST.MF</manifestFile>
              <manifest>

                  <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
              </manifest> 
              <manifestEntries>`

but my code gets stuck cause it cannot get to "car.jar "

the code works fine in eclipse cause it is seeing the car, cause i have it set in the dependencies

---

anything i am missing , or i can check to see if they are getting picked up . 
Any suggestions ?

Comment: The same question is discussed here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24691041/jenkens-plugin-build-with-maven-and-external-jars

Comment: no, i already have done that step. and i get the .hpi file and i a see my external jars under the .hpi >WEB-INF/lib directory.

but when i run the .hpi it cannot find it.... is there a way to define the path where the .hpi when running the code goes to WEB-INF/lib  ?????

maybe in the menifest.mf i am not doing something wrong, or in the pom.xml

Comment: <configuration>
          <archive>
              <manifest>   
                  <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                  <classpathPrefix>./WEB-INF/lib/</classpathPrefix>
              </manifest> 
                 
          </archive>
           
      </configuration>

Comment: i am doing something wrong? 

once again 
1)i have no issue getting the .hpi
2) i have no issue loading the .hpi in jenkins 
3) but when i run the code it cannot find the .jar (i think)
cause when i run it on eclipse as debug it finds the far and goes on.

so anyway to make sure or i need to change or check to make sure it is hitting that .jar and not going off to la la land.

please help been working on this for weeks