# ANY WAY to RUn Debug/ Verbose Mode IN Jenkins, for .HPI plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, xdebug

I am having an issue with .HPI(jenkins Plugin) and so far no one is able to help me.

[JENKINS .HPI dependencies issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27826796/jenkins-hpi-dependencies-issue)     <<  click on this link

so now i am wondering , is there a way that,

When using my .HPI(jenkins Plugin) in jenkins, I can run it in a debug or verbose mode, so i can see on the Console Output(in jenkins) what is exactly  that is going on.

I think i am getting an error cause it is not going to the right .jar ....

when i ran it in eclipse I have no issue. ( i know which jar it is going to in debug mode in eclipse)

if you cannot run the .HPI(jenkins Plugin) in a verbose or debug mode in jenkins , maybe i can run it as a  .WAR ? in a verbose or debug mode in jenkins ?

since i have read that .HPI is very similar to a .WAR.

so that way i can see  in the output console exactly what .jar it is going to.

If someone can help me or point me in a direction it will be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try a debug from Eclipse! If it's not working, just add some logs to your project and when you run it in Jenkins, take a look at the logs in console ( easy if you start Jenkins from command line). Or, in the Jenkins installation folder there should be some log files.

Next time can you put the question more clear? It's somehow hard to understand what you ask.

Comment: thank you so much, i have went back and put more details on the question.

Comment: so the debug in eclipse does show me what jar it is going to. But when i run it on jenkins it fails,( and i cannot see what .jar it is going to in jenkins.) any way in jenkins i can see the log in details, where i can see what jars it goes to, ,like it does in eclipse. ( the console output option does not show which jar it is going to) so need something else.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I read your questions. I'm not sure if you'll can see which jar/ lib is chose by Jenkins.

But, about the link,previous question, I had a problem somehow like you with some libraries and tests, when I worked as plugin developer. I'm not sure if I remember correctly, but, just try, create a folder in your project, let's say libs, put the jars in that folder and add the folder to build-path in eclipse and maven should take care of them.

Not sure if it'll work, but you should try. Sorry I can't help you more!

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply, but that didnot work , i created a folder in my project and put the jars in that and added the build path.. but still not working.

Comment: have you seen this error before ?

FATAL: key [privatechef] not in the list of providers or apis: {}
java.util.NoSuchElementException: key [privatechef] not in the list of providers or apis: {}

Comment: also i tried to point it ./lib using this configuration.. that didnot work either.. i have tried it with and without

Comment: <plugin>
          <groupId>org.jenkins-ci.tools</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-hpi-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>1.95</version>
      <configuration>
          <archive>
              <manifest>   
                  <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                  <classpathPrefix>./lib/</classpathPrefix>
              </manifest> 
          </archive>
          <pluginFirstClassLoader>true</pluginFirstClassLoader>
         <useDefaultManifestFile>true</useDefaultManifestFile>
          
       </configuration>
      </plugin>