# Use maven to extend class files

Tags: java, maven

I have a few class files without sources, and I would like to produce a maven project that extends these classes. As far as I know Maven can only use jar files as dependencies (learned it from this discussion: http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/Does-Maven-dependency-only-work-with-jar-td101642.html), but I am not allowed to build my own jar of them, I can only use dependecies from the central maven repository.

Is there any way I can make my project buildable using maven?

Comment: just add them as `<dependency>`

Comment: AFAIK maven dependencies require group and artifact ids. I only have .class files. Are you aware of a amven dependency mechanism for bare classes?

Comment: You can search the exact artifact from fully qualified classname http://mvnrepository.com/

Comment: These are custom classes, not from any repository.

Comment: do you have source of this class, what is the classname fullyqualified?

Comment: Please explain why you are not allowed to put the class files into a jar.

Comment: @JigarJoshi "I have a few class files without sources"
I guess the exact package names are irrelevant, lets presume some classes from the `com.organisation.project` package, maybe `com.organisation.project.BaseClass` and `com.organisation.project.HelperClass`. They are both stored in .class files.

Comment: You can [construct a jar out of those classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html) and then install that jar to your [local maven repository](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22706173/maven-ojbc-6-jar-not-found-in-central-repository) with your groupId, artifactId and version parameters and then add it to your `pom.xml` as `<dependency>`

Comment: @JimGarrison I can not use any packages that are not available in the central Maven repository. The whole project should be buildable independently from my development environment. I also can't put my own jar into Maven Central, since I don't have rights for the group described by the package.

Currently I got it working by putting the files in a jar, annotating it with my own maven group and artifact ids, placing the jar in my local repository and referencing the dependency from there, but it is not a portable solution.

Answer (score 0):

@zovits, you can make it work, but the solution is not very nice:

Use [maven-antrun-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/) copy classes files to ${project.build.outputDirectory} during pre-compilation-phase, then they will be available for building your classes. You will need to have the classes in a directory structure consistent with Java package names. A good practice would be to host all your classes in a separate VCS and download them from there during that ant task, or include it in your code as binary files.

This is not a nice solution, because:
* You cannot version classes files
* You are obfuscating the dependencies needed for your project
* You don't know how this classes behave, then you

Comment: Thank you, I'll try it as soon as I get home.