# Java - Adding jar dependency in pom.xml

Tags: java, maven, jar, restful-architecture

I have never built my java applications by maven. But when i am trying to do that it's giving me error. 
I have created JAR file from other java application just by exporting as JAR from that application.
Now i want to add this JAR in my maven application. I don't really how to do that.

this is how i have added in pom.xml. But i don't really know what should be it's artifact id.
Seriously what is artifact id?

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>ProjectZen</groupId>
        <artifactId>community</artifactId>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <version>1</version>
        <systemPath>${basedir}\libs\ProjectZen.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
```

I am getting below error

```
Missing artifact ProjectZen:community:jar:1
```

Thanks
Fahad Mullaji

Comment: I would [install it to the local Maven Repo](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html)

Answer (score 11):

If it  is  custom jar  you  need   to do  following things 
   Open cmd  and type  following  command

```
  mvn install:install-file  -Dfile=path-to-your-artifact-jar \
                      -DgroupId=ProjectZen
                      -DartifactId=community
                      -Dversion=1
                      -Dpackaging=jar
                      -DgeneratePom=true
```

Now, the “ProjectZen” jar is copied to your Maven local repository.

In  pom.xml

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>ProjectZen</groupId>
    <artifactId>community</artifactId>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <version>1</version>
    <systemPath>${basedir}\libs\ProjectZen.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

now the “ProjectZen” jar is able to retrieve from your Maven local repository.

Answer (score 6):

change

```
<systemPath>${basedir}\libs\ProjectZen.jar</systemPath>
```

to

```
<systemPath>${basedir}/libs/ProjectZen.jar</systemPath>
```

or [install it in local maven cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22706173/maven-ojbc-6-jar-not-found-in-central-repository)

Answer (score 1):

you should give the format as below. and the slashes used in  are incorrect I suppose. Check the dependency in this format.
...

```
<profiles>
<profile>
  <id>default-tools.jar</id>
  <activation>
    <property>
      <name>java.vendor</name>
      <value>Sun Microsystems Inc.</value>
    </property>
  </activation>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun</groupId>
      <artifactId>tools</artifactId>
      <version>1.4.2</version>
      <scope>system</scope>
      <systemPath>${java.home}/../lib/tools.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</profile>
```

[Reference](http://maven.apache.org/general.html#importing-jars)

...